# How to read a single character from stdin

Tags: c++, character, stdin

I need to make a program that will write A+B if the symbol is +, A-B if the symbol is -, but I dont know how to declare a variable that is + or -. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need to declare a  symbol variable

Comment: I don't know I need a variable that can be a symbol like + and -

Comment: `char from_keyboard;` ?

Comment: It's not working too.

Comment: Please take a primer C++ book. The wording of your question and your comments show us, that you miss fundamental programming language concepts. So simply get a beginner book and start reading. Thanks! BTW: Anybody who knows what the question is? If not, please vote to close unless we get the missing infos here!

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: Your edit changes the content of the question fully! Is it really what OP asks for? Is it var declaration or var reading. I believe we should not do such changes without knowing the OP intend!

Comment: @HaibaoM A variable that is `+` or `-` is a usually a `char` that holds the character `'+'`, `'-'` and so on. However, there are some pitfalls in reading console input and your question isn't entirel clear. If you can provide a [mre] it would help us to understand what exactly you are trying to do and to spot and correct your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strangely enough I can't find a proper duplicate.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << "this is the char I got: " << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

compile your program with

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main
```

and then run it:

```
$ ./main
+
this is the char I got: +
```

Comment: Whats the reason for argc, argv...? gcc complains about unused vars. BTW: return 0 can be omitted also.